# AJAX / JQuery - setInterval stop after keyup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on a live search using ajax

However I'm stuck on the interval part with my searchbox.

What works:

- setInterval running if I am doing nothing with searchbox
- setInterval stop when I am searching (input keyword) in searchbox

What does not work:

- After I deleted my keyword in searchbox, setInterval not running

How could I running setInterval like the first time ?

What I have tried so far :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('.result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }

 var jump = setInterval(load_data, 1000);

 $('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
   clearInterval(jump);
  }
  else
  {
    load_data();
  }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily set the interval again in the else statement after calling `load_data()`